# How to remove unnecessary characters from stdout in python?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, stdout

I have this script:

```
lec_name = request.POST['selected_name']
out = run([sys.executable,'//Projects//altg//algorithm.py',lec_name], shell=False, stdout=PIPE)
print(out.stdout)
```

This script works fine. But I'm not getting the output properly.

OUTPUT:

```
b"Hello World\r\n"
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
Hello World
```

How can I solve this? I found lot of answers about this, but none helped.
I'm using Python 3.7.4, Django 3.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function *strip* to get copy of the array with leading and trailing spaces removed. If you are sure only trailing spaces have to be removed use *rstrip*

Note *b'Hello World'* is an array of byte, not a string, if you want to convert it to a string you can use *decode("utf-8")*

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ python3
Python 3.7.3 (default, Dec 20 2019, 18:57:59) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> b"Hello World\r\n".strip()
b'Hello World'
>>> b"Hello World\r\n".strip().decode("utf-8") 
'Hello World'
>>>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the option `universal_newlines=True`.
Use below udpated code. If you use this you will get the expected result as Hello World .

```
out = run([sys.executable,'//Projects//altg//algorithm.py',lec_name], shell=False, stdout=PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
```